# How to lazy load list items with onclick()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to mimic an ajax feel to loading multiple list items using jquery.

Ultimately i would like to show 10 items and then 10 more after clicking "Load More" button.

My code:

```
<ul id="listings-container">
    <li>List item ...</li>
    <li>List item ...</li>
    <li>List item ...</li>
    <li>List item ...</li>
    <li>List item ...</li>
    <li>List item ...</li>
    <li>List item ...</li>
    <li>List item ...</li>
    <li>List item ...</li>
    <li>List item ...</li>
    <li>List item ...</li>
    <li>List item ...</li>
    <li>List item ...</li>
    <li>List item ...</li>
    <li>List item ...</li>
    <li>List item ...</li>
    <li>List item ...</li>
    <li>List item ...</li>
    <li>List item ...</li>
    <li>List item ...</li>
    <li>List item ...</li>
    <li>List item ...</li>
    <li>List item ...</li>
    <li>List item ...</li>
    <li>List item ...</li>
    <li>List item ...</li>
    <li>List item ...</li>
    <li>List item ...</li>
    <li>List item ...</li>
    <li>List item ...</li>
</ul>

<a class="button" href="#">Load More</a>
```

I tried this, [simplest way to lazy load long <ul> with many <li>s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803546/simplest-way-to-lazy-load-long-ul-with-many-lis/22488331#22488331)

I am trying to accomplish similar with click rather than scroll.

Any ideas?

Comment: bind to `click` instead of `scroll`

Comment: Change `$(window).scroll` to `$(element).click`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/UL8Lx/)

**jQuery**

```
$(".button").on("click", function () {
    $("#listings-container").find("li:hidden:lt(10)").show();
});
```

**CSS**

```
#listings-container li {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kei, how can I start with 10 items?

Comment: Call `$("#listings-container").find("li:hidden:lt(10)").show();` on document load.

Comment: In the CSS, add `#listings-container li:nth-child(-n+11) { display:list-item; }` [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MF94v/)

Comment: I like all of the previous examples, I also added a way to delete the button after you've loaded/reached the entire set. Found here: http://jsfiddle.net/mkormendy/udL79xwz/

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if you're using **bootstrap tab panel** and **lazy loading**, it works well for loading the first tab (default active) but not for when you clicked to other tabs, images will not load unless you scroll.

Here is a workaround for this issue, just add the below javascript and you'll be fine. The logic is simple, when the tab is clicked, trigger a scroll.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        $(window).trigger('scroll');
    });
});
```

For more information about `shown.bs.tab` and other functions please refer to this link: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_tab.asp

Hope this helps.